# Upload files and store titles into database

Tags: html, codeigniter

Controller :

```
class gallery extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('gallery_model');
        if($this->input->post('upload'))
        {
            $this->gallery_model->do_upload();
        }
        $data['images'] = $this->gallery_model->get_images();
        $this->load->view('gallery',$data);

}
```

}
Model :

```
<?php 

class gallery_model extends CI_Model {

    var $gallery_path;
    var $gallery_path_url;
    function gallery_model()
    {
        $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../images');
        $this->gallery_path_url = base_url().'images/';
    }

    function do_upload()

    {
        $config = array(
                'allowed_types' => 'jpeg|jpg|gif|png',
                'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path
            );
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload();
        $image_data = $this->upload->data();
        $config = array(
            'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
            'new_image' => $this->gallery_path. '/thumbs',
            'maintain_ration' => TRUE,
            'width' => 150,
            'height' =>150
            );
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

    }
}
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My gallery</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>

</head>
<body>
<div id="upload">
    <?php 
        echo form_open_multipart('gallery');
        echo form_upload('userfile');
        echo form_submit('upload','Upload');
        echo form_close(); 
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to do something like an photo album. In the upload form i upload photos in images folder and the thumb into thumb folder. What i want to do is to store the titles of pictures into the database and retrieve from there and i don't know how to store the pictures titles.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a text field to your form for Image Title, pass it to your do_upload method from the gallery model, or separately into a new image database model (to connect and query your database).

I'm writing this on the fly and is untested. Some advice to the process, make sure you are cleaning the inputs. Codeigniter does a great job at this, but it's good coding to share that advice. Also, you should like an image with its title. I would maybe also pass to the database, the dir path of the image and/or its thumb path. It also makes calling the image from gallery easier as you are already querying the Database for meta data. Something like a `foreach($img in$result){ echo $img['title']." - ".echo $img['path'];}` to produce "My title - http://example.com/images/thumb/1234.jpg"

### View (input)

```
 ..
  echo form_input('imgTitle', 'Image Title');
 ..
```

### Controller

```
 ..
if($this->input->post('upload'))
 {
  $data['imgTitle'] = $this->input->post('imgTitle'); //Assigns the post value to the data array so you can pass it via $data to your views
  $this->gallery_model->do_upload($data['imgTitle']);
 }
..
```

### Model

```
 ..
function do_upload($imgTitle=null) //passes a variable as NULL unless specified
{
..
$DB1 = $this->load->database(); //specify db connection/name
$data = array(
  'title' => $imgTitle, //passed from controller
   'name' => 'My Name');
$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
..
}
```